# Remove RAID0 single hard drive and put it in a USB enclosure

Tags: windows, hard-drive, raid, ntfs

My question is simple but searching around I can't find an answer.  I have a single hard drive that was brand new and I attached it to a Dell H700 RAID card.  The reason is, I needed to backup data from another computer that didn't have any more free space for another physical hard drive so I'm copying the data over the network.  After it's done, I want to remove the hard drive from the H700, and put it in a USB enclosure because I need all of the HDD slots in the server for a RAID array (a real one, not a single HD).  My question is: When I added the new hard drive, the RAID card initialized it.  Will there be any RAID configuration in the beginning sectors of the hard drive that'll prevent the data from being read once it's put in a USB enclosure since the RAID card had to make it "RAID 0" even though it's a single hard drive?  The OS is Windows and the file system is NTFS.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up going through the process and can report happily that YES, after copying whatever, you can offline the disk in diskmgmt.msc, and then put it in a USB enclosure and it came back up just fine.  In my specific case, diskmgmt.msc through the USB enclosure showed 513mb unallocated to the NTFS filesystem.  Hope this helps somebody else.